# Drop shadow preventing links in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

The website I'm designing has a fixed menu behind the body. When the menu icon is clicked some jquery shifts the body left. I've put a shadow on the body to make the fixed menu look like it's positioned underneath. In chrome, firefox, and safari everything works flawlessly. But in Internet Explorer the links in this menu can't be clicked because of the drop shadow coming from the body. Is there an easy fix to this, or a way to easily disable the css on ie?

[image]

Here's the relevant code:

The shadow on the main content

```
.wrapper {
-webkit-box-shadow: 3px 0px 10px 1px rgba(0,0,0,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 3px 0px 10px 1px rgba(0,0,0,1);
box-shadow: 3px 0px 10px 1px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

The fixed menu that displays when the menu button is clicked.

```
.sidemenu {
position: fixed;
right: 0px;
top: 0px;
width: 260px;
height: 100%;
background: #2b2b2b;
z-index: -10;
overflow: hidden;
transition: 0.2s;
color: white;
text-align: center;
}
```

**This worked:**
Added a javascript function to detect Internet Explorer.

```
if (detectIE() != false) {
    $('.sidemenu').css('zIndex', '1000');
}
```

When the menu is clicked, the index is adjusted on ie to bypass all the other layers. Works well enough.

Comment: hey dude, please add some of your actual code or jsfiddle demo to debug for you.

Comment: can you add the HTML of what is inside .sidemenu ?

Comment: Completely removed the shadow, and the links and hovers wouldn't work on ie 11.  The problems gotta be z-index bug along with some divs in the html so i'll just dig through a little deeper. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmmm.. a couple things would help; like *WHICH* version of IE are you seeing this issue on?

But, sounds like setting a `z-index:`  to higher on these links could do the trick.

```
.menu { 
  position: relative; // works best if parent is set to relative
}

.menu li a { 
   // all it's styles
   z-index: 1001; //add
}
```

If the above doesn't work alone, try setting a lower `z-index` to the page wrapper or `<body>` if that's all you have to work with in this scenario. `Eg. z-index: 888;` for info on stacking order with z-index check this [reference (updated)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/Adding_z-index).

*But you'll really need to show us the actual code your using to fully debug this.*

I'm curious how your writing your `box-shadow:` you shouldn't have to do more then this *(only to outer element you want this effect on, try moving to page wrapper instead of body tag)*

```
.shadow {
   -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 10px #000000;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
   box-shadow:         inset 0 0 10px #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What is your current CSS for the `box-shadow` ? have you implemented the correct Microsoft filters by chance?

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius=3,MakeShadow=true,ShadowOpacity=0.30);
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius=3,MakeShadow=true,ShadowOpacity=0.30)";
zoom: 1;
```

Just a thought, make sure to include all vendor/browser specifics.